# Clustering+Regression-the right approach or not?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, regression, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have a task of prognosing the quickness of selling goods (for example, in one category). E.g, the client inputs the price that he wants his item to be sold and the algorithm should displays that it will be sold with the inputed price for n days. And it should have 3 intervals of quick, medium and long sell. Like in the picture:[image]

The question: how exactly should I prepare the algorithm?

My suggestion: use clustering technics for understanding this three price ranges and then solving regression task for each cluster for predicting the number of days. Is it a right concept to do?

Comment: In general, there is no one good answer for questions like this, since this is all about your data, its characteristics and nature. There are no "ultimate" solutions. What you are proposing is probably suboptimal, since you are artificially dividing problem to multiple subproblems and consequently - you make your model unable to reason in one cluster using data from the other one, while even your plot has a clear relation across **all the data**. Consequently - I do not see any point in such an approach, you should rather build a single regression model and "cut it" afterwards if you need.

Comment: I ve read some articles that this approach could increase the accuracy of model comparing to simple regression

Comment: @lejlot pointed out that there is no set approach or else it would not been modeling but rather following the process. You do find ref in literature supporting your approach. Rather why not take both approach (your's and lejlot's) and then compare. Plus report here so that other's can benefit as well.

Comment: What do you think: http://ncss.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Regression_Clustering.pdf

Comment: @HalfPintBoy, you can find milions of bad examples in literature :-) I am simply saying - do not **remove data** from your model before you even started work. Always start process with full data and try to tweak things **afterwards**. Starting off with tweaked approach rarely makes any sense. This is why I said that your approach is **probably** suboptimal, as it reduces amount of information in your models, thus **probably** it will be worse. I am assuming here using very strong joint model on top, which might not be fully feasible for your data, but I do not know your data, so-**probably**.

Comment: @HalfPintBoy - and in order to refer to the link provided, the first image is perfect, it clearly shows that **there is no relation** between regressed value in one cluster and another, and this is **the only** setting when you should go this way. If there is **any information** shared across clusters that cannot be apriori built into the model (like linear structure in their example) but instead-has to be learnt, you should not cluster before hand.You can, however, cluster and add cluster information as another feature-this way your model will be able to fit independent submodels to each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here, and I think the answer to each lies in a different domain:

1. Given an input price, predict how long will it take to sell the item. This is a well defined prediction problem, and can be tackled using ML algorithms. e.g. use your entire dataset to train and test a regression model for prediction.
2. Translate the prediction into a class: quick-, medium- or slow-sell. This problem is product oriented - there doesn't seem to be any concrete data allowing you to train a classifier on this translation; and I agree with @anony-mousse that using unsupervised learning might not yield easy-to-use results.

You can either consult your users or a product manager on reasonable thresholds to use (there might be considerations here like the type of item, season etc.), or try getting some additional data in order to train a supervised classifier.

E.g. you could ask your users, post-sell, if they think the sell was quick, medium or slow. Then you'll have some data to use for thresholding or for classification.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simply **define thesholds** of 10 days and 31 days. Keep it *simple*.

Because these are the values the users will want to understand. If you use clustering, you may end up with 0.31415 days or similar nonintuitive values that you cannot explain to the user anyway.